# Git pull "error: cannot lock ref " problem

Tags: git

```
$ git pull
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/thing_15': 'refs/remotes/origin/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/thing_15'
From https://git.mycompany.com/projects/myproject
```

This was the error when I did a pull on my project folder. It looks like

```
git fetch -p
```

resolves the issue. I have read this doc but not sure what this prunes in my local other than references to deleted branches. Can someone explain in more details, I do not think anyone messed with the tags in the repo?

> -p
>
> --prune
>
> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they
> are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a
> --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for
> example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they
> are also subject to pruning. Supplying --prune-tags is a shorthand for
> providing the tag refspec.

Comment: Note: see my answer, as well as the accepted one, for the explanation part.

Comment: But when we get the error and the solution are different then the one marked as duplicate of this.

Comment: The solution is the same: delete the unwanted remote-tracking name, using `git fetch -p` or `git remote prune origin` (both achieve the same result, except for some old versions of Git that have a bug where one works and the other doesn't).

Comment: ok I will up your answer there. thanks torek.